# How do I combine two filter_complex?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have these two filters that respectively, work just fine, but I can't seem to combine them.

Overlay with opacity

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i bar.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; [0:v][zork]overlay"  -vcodec libx264 myresult.mp4
```

Overlay with left to right movement

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i bar.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lte(-w+(t)*100,100),-w+(t)*100,100)':y=0[out]" -map "[out]" -y out.mp4
```

End goal is to have my input picture with 0.5 opacity, and animated moving left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i bar.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[zork];[0:v][zork]overlay=x='if(lte(-w+(t)*100,100),-w+(t)*100,100)':y=0" output.mp4
```